# ffmpeg open rtsp stream and keep encoded until a frame is read

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have an ip camera which is live streaming 24/7.

I want to open the rtsp stream with ffmpeg on a client, but since continuously decoding the stream is cpu-intensive, I want to keep the stream encoded until I specifically request for a frame

How can I achieve this (preferable in python, but C is ok too)?

Using ffmpeg-python, I can open a stream and keep it raw, but how do I make sure that when I request a frame from the encoded stream, I start reading the frame from the beginning of the frame?

Comment: What is ffmpeg doing when you don't request a frame? The best answer seems to be "just run ffmpeg when you need to decode the stream" but there must be more to it than that...

Comment: It is not so simple because we can't just start decoding at the beginning of an encoded frame, we have to start decoding at the beginning of a key frame. You may try using [segment](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) muxer for splitting the decoded video into small segments that stats with a key frame.

Comment: So far what I managed is to keep the encoded stream in a container, which acts like a buffer, so when I request a frame I get the "next" frame in the buffer, not the last frame that entered the buffer (which is what I would want).  The keyframes approach is a good idea, I'll play around with it and see hat I arrive at